# Structure of the Haskell runtime on multicore processors

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing, runtime, multicore, numa

I understand that the Haskell runtime creates an OS thread on every core or so. Lightweight threads / user threads are then scheduled by the runtime onto these pre-deployed OS threads. Roughly.

But how is the Haskell runtime structured - is it monolithic, or made up of seperate parts?

What I really want to know is how scalable and distributable the RT itself is across cores - for example, can I in theory have a 1000 core system and start a Haskell RT on 5% of the cores (either as 50 independent or distributed RTs)?

Comment: Too many questions.

Comment: @ StephenC: But I think they were run-up questions to the real issue, so I've edited to reduce clutter and emphasise the real question.

Comment: 1000-core shared memory systems must be NUMA with high inter-node penalties so the question may be how much NUMA support is already built in. @J Fritsch: You should be more specific - your current question is too vague. The answer will depend on particular architecture of the machine at hand and on your computational problem.

Comment: @nponeccop I don;t think about a specific system. I recently read that e.g. the Erlang VM itself should be getting ready soon to be distributable or to have multiple (communicating?) instances running each on a separate core. http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~trinder/RELEASEfactsheet.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Design of the multicore runtime:

- [How the multicore runtime is designed](http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/papers/multicore-ghc.pdf)
- [The multicore garbage collector with thread-local heaps](http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/papers/local-gc.pdf)
- [How the garbage collector services work](http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/papers/parallel-gc.pdf)

Cloud Haskell (distributed Haskell):

- [Towards Haskell in the Cloud](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/parallel/remote.pdf)
- [Cloud Haskell: an appetizer](http://www.well-typed.com/blog/68)

Comment: Not really matching my question. I think that in last consequence and largest scale the RT must be itself distributable and ready for multicore. Not only enabling parallel processing for the applications that it executes.

Comment: @JFritsch I think you need to read (the links in) this answer more carefully.

Comment: @JFritsch the links above describe the architecture of the runtime on multicore and distributed systems. They are the primary reference material for such information.

Comment: Thanks. I found a better starting point though: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts